# Php submit form with select option condition

Tags: php, forms

I want to submitting form data into database, but firstly first it's should be filtered by select option before inserting it. Below is my form view:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
<select name="choose">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
<!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> -->
```

And this is process form:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
switch(true) {
    case  ( isset($_POST['choose']) == "1" ):
        echo "you choose 1";
        break;
    case  ( isset($_POST['choose']) == "2" ):
        echo "you choose 2";
        break;
    case  ( isset($_POST['choose']) == "" ):
        echo "you didn't choose anything";
        default;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

}

For example if I select `Two`, the result is:

```
you choose 1
Array
(
    [name] => aaaaaaaa
    [username] => bbbbbbbbb
    [choose] => 2
    [submit] => 
)
```

Which is still displaying `you choose 1` refers to the first case.
What should I do to filter the data before sending it into database? At least how can I know the status of the data, whether it's in `1, 2,` or `you didn't choose anything`? Make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your using `isset()` wrongly, it returns true\false

Comment: You also don't need so many `isset()` calls, just the first one is fine. If it's set before running the switch statements, why would it all of a sudden not be set anymore?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton the subsequent `isset()` calls are on a different variable, though still unnecessary.

Comment: @Trey Didn't notice that, but yeah still unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rework your switch case, the switch should be a variable that can evaluate to different values, and the cases are those values:

```
switch($_POST['choose']){
    case "1":
        echo "you choose 1";
        break;
    case "2":
        echo "you choose 2";
        break;
    case "":
        echo "you didn't choose anything";
        break;
}
```

The `default` keyword can be used as a last case when none of the cases match the value, it acts as an "else" in a switch case scenario:

```
switch($some_val){
    case "1":
        echo "you entered a 1!";
        break;
    default:
        echo "You didn't enter a 1!!";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Note you don't really need the quotes on case because case is a number.

Comment: If he is evaluating it as a string, I'll treat it as a string, I never assume `1=="1"`

Comment: Fair enough. Though I still think you should change `case "":` to `default:`, But I understand that's straight from OP's code and you explained it below :)

Comment: It's hard to tell since I don't know what he's doing, I generally agree, but what if you don't want to output anything if someone sent a 4?

Comment: Very true. Thinking about it now, I think your last code snippet is a good enough explanation of the way to properly handle invalid cases.

Comment: by that I mean, if his input isn't sanitized to ensure that the value is a valid selection and the user "added" an invalid value there, we just assume they are being malicious and ignore them ;)

Comment: Great, I changed my code as suggested and it was working fine. I did forget to add `<option value="">Please Choose</option>` in select option.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
switch(true) {
    case  ( isset($_POST['choose']) == "1" ):
        echo "you choose 1";
        break;
    case  ( isset($_POST['choose']) == "2" ):
        echo "you choose 2";
        break;
    case  ( isset($_POST['choose']) == "" ):
        echo "you didn't choose anything";
        default;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$choose = isset($_POST['choose']) ? $_POST['choose'] : '';
switch($choose) {
    case  "1" :
        echo "you choose 1";
        break;
    case  "2" :
        echo "you choose 2";
        break;
    default;
        echo "you didn't choose anything";            
    }
}
```

`isset()` only returns true/false values. This can cause to unexpected/unintended behaviors when used the way you are using it. 
If your going to use a switch case you need something to test on. and `true` is not a proper test. `true` will only ever be 1. Because 0 is false and any other value is true. But the keyword true is really just a 1.

So assigning the value to a variable is a lot safer to test with then using the `$_POST['choose']` in the switch. Now we have a proper variable to test with and we can reach one of our 3 test cases. And using the ternary operator is just a short hand for an if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet your switch use is not correct. It should be like this:

```
switch($_POST['choose']) { // what is being compared
    case 1: // what if it's 1
        echo "you choose 1";
        break;
    case 2: // what if it's 2
        echo "you choose 2";
        break;
    default: // what else
        echo "you didn't choose anything";
        break;
}
```

But default in your case isn't anything because you have fixed options.

Also, `isset()` is only to know if a variable exists. It will not tell you the value of it. It's thinked to do something like

```
if(isset($_POST['variable'])){
    $variable = $_POST['variable'];
}else{
    $variable = "";
}
```

Then you would use the new `$variable`.

This is useful because some code will not work if you try to get undefined variables.

**EDIT** (thanks to GrumpyCrouton):

Or the short version:

```
$variable = isset($_POST['variable']) ? $_POST['variable'] : '';
```

Where first (after `=`) you are saying the condition, after `?` you are saying the value if `true` and after the `:` you are saying the value if `false`.

Comment: Note you could shorten your `if { } else { }` to a single line ternary `$variable = isset($_POST['variable']) ? $_POST['variable'] : '';` (1 line that's still readable versus 5 lines)

Comment: I know it, but it can be easier to understand if you don't know how it works in this way. I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Now we have the null coalescing operator there's some labour saving: `$choose = $_POST['choose'] ?? null;`.  That also reduces the switch: `switch ($_POST['choose'] ?? null):`.  There's an outside chance someone may submit the form without some attributes, or with different values to the choices we present them.